PostGIS installation in PostgreSQL 17
I want to install PostGIS with the Stack Builder 4.2.1 for PostgreSQL 17. However, I dont have the option of choosing PostGIS. The category "spatial extension" is simply missing. A screenshot of the situation is down below. How do I procceed?


is it under Add-ons?

Unfortunately, it is not:(

I had the same problem with Postgres 17. So I installed 16.4. From here: PostGIS 3.4.2: "this version requires PostgreSQL 12-16". Then PostGIS was available in Stack Builder

I did the same. I guess PostGIS is not available for Postgres 17 yet!?

Postgis 3.5 is now compatible with Postgres 17 but should be installed separately.

There's a 17.0+3.4.3 straight from PostGIS if you can trade the Stack Builder for Docker. I think PostGIS docker images get pushed out every Monday at 5:15 automatically by their github workflow, while Stack Builder needs to be handled by someone at EDB adding the option, or they have some other workflow that lags behind the one at PostGIS by a bit.

EDB also maintains their own docker images which are a bit more up to date.
